# Crop text out of binary image OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, crop

How can I crop the image so that only the text is included in the image using OpenCV?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Approach**

1. Dilating the image in in the vertical and horizontal direction
2. Finding the bounding rectangle
3. Cropping the image

---

**Code**

```
# reading the input image in grayscale image
image = cv2.imread('image2.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
image /= 255
if image is None:
    print 'Can not find/read the image data'
# Defining ver and hor kernel
N = 5
kernel = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=np.uint8)
kernel[2,:] = 1
dilated_image = cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations=2)

kernel = np.zeros((N,N), dtype=np.uint8)
kernel[:,2] = 1
dilated_image = cv2.dilate(dilated_image, kernel, iterations=2)
image *= 255

# finding contours in the dilated image
contours,a = cv2.findContours(dilated_image,cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# finding bounding rectangle using contours data points
rect = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])
pt1 = (rect[0],rect[1])
pt2 = (rect[0]+rect[2],rect[1]+rect[3])
cv2.rectangle(image,pt1,pt2,(100,100,100),thickness=2)

# extracting the rectangle
text = image[rect[1]:rect[1]+rect[3],rect[0]:rect[0]+rect[2]]

plt.subplot(1,2,1), plt.imshow(image,'gray')
plt.subplot(1,2,2), plt.imshow(text,'gray')

plt.show()
```

---

**Output**

[image: Figure1-Dilated Image]

[image: Figure2-Bounding Rect]

[image: Figure3-Cropped Image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have pixel information you could draw a [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) around the white text. Once that you have the hull, you can get the lowest and highest x and y coordinate and use those as your rectangle coordinates so that you could crop the rest of the image.

An example of how to obtain a convex hull in Open_CV (C++) is available [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html).

It might be a good idea to apply some filter on the image (maybe use the [erosion](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html) filter) so that you can remove any false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Take **projection** of white pixels in x-direction and y-direction. The lowest and highest values in x and y direction are bound of your rectangle's y and x co-ordinates respectively.
This solution is for simple situations with low processing and in-place calculation.